# Download the Data Replicator feed messages raises itgencsr003 error

Tags: invantive-sql

I execute the following statement to download the messages on the Data Replicator feed:

```
alter persistent cache download feed
```

This returns the following error:

```
alter persistent cache download feed
Error itgencsr003: Could not determine Data Replicator messages. (L123456)

Access not available for license contract 'L123456' with this token.

Please check whether the token in the facts database is not intended for use with a different license contract code.
```

What should I do to download the messages?

Answer (score 2):

You have to either set or include a token.

For example:

> Value:
>
> ```
> your_token
> ```
>
> Set with:
>
> ```
> alter persistent cache set token 'your_token'
> ```
>
> See
>   https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/invantive-sql-grammar/invantive-sql-grammar-17.30.html#alterPersistentCacheSetStatement
>
> Or include as:
>
> ```
> alter persistent cache download feed token 'your_token'
> ```
>
> See
>   https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/invantive-sql-grammar/invantive-sql-grammar-17.30.html#alterPersistentCacheDownloadStatement